# Android MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate

Tags: android, sdk, maps, fingerprint

I have some issues obtaining the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate . I type this in the command line : `keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android` . I get " keytool is not recognized as an internal or external command" . [This is my command line .](http://i52.tinypic.com/x37skk.png)

I would really appreciate an answer asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you don't have the jdk's bin folder in your system's path.

In windows: c:\Programs file\Java\jdk1.**X**.**Y**\bin\

alternatively, if you are using Eclipse, you can install the keytool from [here](http://keytool.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

In your command prompt first locate your `keytool` which you can find it in your `bin inside jdk`. Now try above command, it will recognize it.

```
Android MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate
```

you can follow this [link](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) and [this](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can always retrieve the fingerprints of the debug keystore inside the Eclipse that came with your version of Android SDK.
Open the *Window*->*Preferences* dialog. There under *Android*->*Build* you see the following information:

- Default debug keystore location
- MD5 fingerprint
- SHA1 fingerprint

It's there possible to also switch to a custom debug keystore.